# New to Python- How do I store a biased number generator as function?

Tags: python, function, nonetype

This isn't for any project or anything, just messing around. (Was doing this in a python shell)

```
import random
def rand1():
    random.gauss(0, 0.1) * 0.3 + random.gauss(0, 3) * 0.7

rand1() + 1
```

It comes up with

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Why does the `rand1()` not work in math operations?
Even if I store it in a variable like `rand2 = rand1()` it still comes up with the same message. Is there a way to store it as a float rather than NoneType?

Comment: You're not returning anything from your function, so it returns `None`.

Comment: you need to return your result

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean return something from my function?

Comment: @Cogswellx: See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for a function is

```
def functionname():
# function operations - this is just a comment, noted by the #!
<tab>x = 2 + 2
<tab>return x
```

This "returns `x`" to the caller. Tabs `<tab>` are necessary to let the interpreter know it is part of the function.

From what I read, and based on what I wrote, I assume you mean this:

```
import random
def rand1():
    return random.gauss(0, 0.1) * 0.3 + random.gauss(0, 3) * 0.7

rand1() + 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm starting to get it now. Sorry for the silly question (You guys answer really fast!)

Comment: @Cogswellx No question is a silly question. If you're sitting in front of a compiler/interpreter and wondering what to write, this is the right place to ask. If this solved your problem, click the checkmark.